# Single Action Controllers and ReSharper's Solution-Wide Analysis

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, resharper

We've got an ASP.NET MVC 3 project that uses [single action controllers](http://rodolfograve.blogspot.com/2011/05/teamcommons-mvc-single-responsibility.html), and ReSharper doesn't like it. For example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoRegister", "Account")) {
```

It doesn't like either `DoRegister` or `Account`, because it's looking for a class `AccountController` with an action `DoRegister`. What we've actually got is a folder `Controllers\Account`, with a single-action class `DoRegister`.

Can I teach ReSharper about this? If not, can I get it to ignore this particular pattern?

I know that I can right-click and Ignore Errors in the Errors in Solution window, but this only lasts until I pull an updated version of the code from source control, which gets annoying quite quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid ReSharper supports only default MVC convention.

But you can disable MVC analysis:

1. At All

   ReSharper->Options->ASP.NET->Other->Enable ASP.NET MVC references
2. On all unknown action and controller errors

   Alt+Enter on error, Inspection Options for "Unknown Symbol"
3. At that specific place

   Again, Alt+Enter on error, Supress Inspection "Unknown Symbol" with comment.